# android How to switch between Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 3 activities. start / game / finish, I want to go start to game, game to finish, finish to start. but when I use Intent one to another when I finish() "finish" Its come back to game. It should come back to start. so It needs a design kind of all Intents under start activity.

so I tried this one and expected when I finish() "finish" application will be destroy but It didnt work

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FinishScreen.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Q: so how can I start finish activity Intent under start activity but from game activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `startActivity(...)` in "game" `Activity` to start the "finish" `Activity`, immediately call `finish()` so "game" terminates. If you do that then BACK in the "finish" `Activity` will return to "start" because "game" self-terminated.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FinishScreen.class); 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: lol, admittedly similar questions are fairly common here on SO but it was a simple one for me to answer and the Android "manual" is quite a big one. In 14 months programming Android I probably only covered 20% of the developers pages and I still get some simple stuff wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

The finish() method should work, try with: System.exit(0);

Comment: I think System.exit(0) completely kills your app, isn't it?

Comment: I wanna return to start activity from finish activity. but It return to game.

Comment: As a rule, don't ever use `System.exit(...)`. A call to `finish()` on its own will kill an `Activity` cleanly.

Comment: I know system.exit.. but It not even close what I asked as an answer.. I need answer about Intents pls read carefully.. thanks